# Centering responsive expand icon in datatables

Tags: html, css, datatable

EDIT:

---

So I was able to move the icon down manually by selecting the psuedo element and manually adding some margin,

```
td::before {
    margin-top:8px;
}
```

but obviously this won't scale if my row gets any larger vertically for some reason. Still looking for a way to Center it.

---

So I'm trying to center the responsive expand icon in my datatable vertically (Was able to center all the content with this line)

```
.table > tbody > tr > td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But this seems to still leave my icon unaffected. I'm also not really sure how to create a rule for it to catch it since its being dynamically generated by Datatables.

**Here is the issue,**

[image: Icon Center Issue]

**Here is an inspection of the element.**

[image]

I assume I just need to make a css rule to take care of this but I can't think of what needs to happen here.

Comment: try selecting the pseudo element in td and target that in css

Comment: looks like you figured it out. have a nice day

Comment: @karthick Almost thanks for the help on selecting. Still looking for a more scalable solution if anyone knows.

Comment: sorry about that didnt read your edit completely

Comment: what is full css of td::before?

Answer (score 0):

Here in aexample on how to center an icon in pseudo class vertically centered to container

```css
.box {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.box:after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f055";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="box">
 +15.00$
</div>
```

Comment: Hm, I can see how this works in your example, but when I try to apply some of the styling to the td::before it doesn't work. Any idea which rules I need to move over?

Comment: check if they are overriden by thew default datatables css, maybe you have to put !important